# Tableau desktop not showing parameters and sets in worksheet?

Tags: tableau-api

Tableau desktop not showing parameters and sets in worksheet ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to create filter first then only it will be visible under filter .

Below is the link how to create filter

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-filter-actions-dashboards

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that there are no `parameters` and `sets` as available.

Create a parameter `temp Param` and see.

It should appear below `Measure`, in the `Parameter` tab.